# bug with jquery-mobile radio button display

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, radio-button, jquery-mobile-radio

hi i m creating a mobil apps and i have a probleme with my radio buttons, they randomly change
apparence. I don t get why. on navigator it's fine, but on mobile phone it's very ugly ...
champ mobile and tel are requested by an ajax request(dont know if it matter).

took 2 screen

1. this one look to not bug on mobile phone
   [image]
2. this one look to bug (it comes more often than the first).
   [image]

made a jsfiddle in comment

Comment: jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/xED4q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to remove `"ui-btn-icon-left"`